# Python syntax highlighting

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting

Is there already a standard way to highlight Python source code **with high quality like within the IDLE** (i. e. with the IDLE colors and highlighting rules)?

- solutions based on `lstlistings` (like `pythonhighlight`) color too naively. E. g., they do not color the function name within the function definition and the function's use differently.
- `pygments` (combined with `minted` / `verbments`) does not have an IDLE style for Python and I was not able to find a shared user-defined style implementing the IDLE color scheme in the Internet.
- simply making screenshots is not flexible enough. (has to be repeated every time the source code changes)

(Yes, I am a little bit fastidiously.)

It is necessary that umlauts are supported.

Comment: minted python styles are probably best you are going to find out of the box. You could try asking at a general python forum or stackoverflow if anyone has a pygments config closer to the idle style.

Comment: If you are a Python developer anyway, it's quite easy to write a custom minted style. Start with what you think comes closest or with something minimal like vs and customize colors and matched classes to your needs.